# Problem related with SCOPED_SESSION sqlalchemy in python 3.11

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have encountered a problem that I can't figure out how to solve.

There is a flask application. Many tests are written for it.
There are fixtures db_session and db_scoped_session, including a global variable SCOPED_SESSION. The handlers are implemented as views.

The mentioned fixtures - db_session and db_scoped_session and the SCOPED_SESSION object are different objects, judging by the id. This is true for both the early - python 3.9 and the new - 3.11 that we have migrated to. With the early version of python no problems were indicated, while with the version of python 3.11 the tests crashed, the main cause of which is an error - DetachedInstanceError.

Read more about the error.

It occurs when we try to access an object detached from its session.

When an object is loaded into a session, it is in persistent state - this means that any changes are tracked by the session. When the session is closed, the objects associated with that session go into detached state, which leads to the above error.

1. Believing that the error is due to the fact that we use different sessions for the fixtures and for the views themselves, I moved all the fixtures to the same session. That didn't help:)
2. The session is cleared in the teardown_appcontext callable method - by the __remove_session object. _Removing this method fixed this problem, but caused new problems of a different nature.

sqlalchemy version is 1.3.28

Can you please give me a hint as to what the problem could be related to?

example:

```
# view.py
class SomeView:
    def get_one(self, id):
        return some_thing

# flask_app.py
from flask_admin import Admin
from view import SomeView

admin = Admin(...)

admin.add_view(SomeView(...), endpoint='/some_endpoint/')

# worker.py

class Worker(...):
    def _init_application(self):
        self._flask_app = Flask(...)
        ...
        self._flask_app.teardown_appcontext(self._remove_session)
        ...
    def _remove_session(self, response_or_exc):
        SCOPED_SESSION.remove()
        return response_or_exc

# test_case.py

def test_edit_get(test_object, client:FlaskClient, request_headers) -> None:

        response: TestResponse = client.get(
            f'/some_endpoint/?id={test_object.id}',
            headers=request_headers
        )
        assert response.status_code == 200
        # Error coming here
        print(test_object.id) # DetachedInstanceError
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].